# Log multiple returned values in Go

Tags: logging, go, multiple-value

Is there an idiomatic way to log result of a function returning multiple values? This won't compile:

```
import "log"
func returnPair() (int,int) {
    return 42, 24
}
func main() {
    log.Printf("Returned %v", returnPair())
}

prog.go:7: multiple-value returnPair() in single-value context
```

UPD summary (special thanks to @rvignacio):

This is a peculiarity in Go syntax:

```
func eat(args ...interface{}) {}

func eatWithSpice(spice string, args ...interface{}) {}

func main() {
    eat(returnPair()) // this works
    eatWithSpice("pepper", returnPair()) // this does not
}
```

*As a special case, if the return values of a function or method g are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method f, then the call f(g(parameters_of_g)) will invoke f after binding the return values of g to the parameters of f in order. The call of f must contain no parameters other than the call of g, and g must have at least one return value. If f has a final ... parameter, it is assigned the return values of g that remain after assignment of regular parameters.* (http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls)

Comment: [According to the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters), `eatWithSpice("pepper", returnPair())` isn't an inconsistence, it should be `eatWithSpice("pepper", returnPair()...)`

Comment: @rvignacio Does not work: http://play.golang.org/p/fz-452hKT7

Comment: Sorry, I missed you were returning multiple values, [here's the correct explanation](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=973): "As a special case, if the return parameters of a function or method g are equal in number and individually assignable to the parameters of another function or method f, then the call f(g(parameters_of_g)) will invoke f after binding the return values of g to the parameters of f in order. **No other special cases for function calls are allowed.**"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can assign those returning values first:

```
a, b := returnPair()
log.Printf("Returned %d %d", a, b
```

You can see an example in "[Multiple return values from Go functions](http://golangtutorials.blogspot.fr/2011/06/return-values-from-go-functions.html)".

Using a multiple returning value directly in `Println` works though (since it accepts [variadic parameters](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)):

In your case: [<kbd>play.golang.org</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/_ugHDMBfC7)

```
package main

import "log"

func returnPair() (a int, b int) {
    return 42, 24
}
func main() {
    log.Println(returnPair())
}
```

Output:

```
2009/11/10 23:00:00 42 24
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid

Comment: @grep I have added the other approach: using directly Println

Answer (score 2):

I aprrove the method of VonC, which is cleaner, but if you really want, you can get inspired by the `Must()` kind of function and do something like this:

http://play.golang.org/p/_dik4rSFBC

```
package main

import "fmt"

func returnPair() (int, int) {
    return 42, 24
}

func displayPair(a, b interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(a, b)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("pair: %v\n", displayPair(returnPair()))
}
```

EDIT:

Or more generic:

http://play.golang.org/p/DjPur-aatt

```
package main

import "fmt"

func returnPair() (int, int) {
    return 42, 24
}

func returnTriple() (int, int, int) {
    return 42, 24, 10
}

func displayPair(elem ...interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprint(elem...)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("pair: %v, triple %v\n", displayPair(returnPair()), displayPair(returnTriple()))
}
```

Comment: This looks good enough: `fmt.Printf("returned %v", fmt.Sprint(returnPair()))`

Comment: Lol, indeed, much simpler :p. Don't know why I called a displayPair in my second example ^^